# Django Form Wizard with Conditional Questions

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements, django-formwizard

In my Django application, I currently have a form wizard with a few form classes.  I would like to have the ability to have conditional questions.  Meaning if the user selects yes for a certain question, another question within the form will become required and javascript will make the question visible.  I found an example of how to do this online, however it doesn't work.  Any suggestions on how I can create this functionality?

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):

COOL_LIST = (
    ('cool','Cool'),
    ('really cool','Really Cool'),
)

YES, NO = 'yes','no'

YES_NO = (
    (YES,'Yes'),
    (NO,'No'),
)

are_you_cool = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YES_NO,label='Are you cool?')
how_cool = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=COOL_LIST,label='How cool are you?')

def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

    if data and data.get('are_you_cool', None) == self.YES:
        self.fields['how_cool'].required = True
```

Comment: You have to understand the web client-server flow. For your issue you've two choices: you chain forms, and thus for each form sent to the client and submited by him, the server sends to the client a new form according to your conditions. This is the standard solution. Another is: you send only one form to the client, but when he fills the fields, the form change __whithout any communication with your server__. This is the Ajax way, what do you prefer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `__init__` method of your form with custom `clean_are_you_cool` method. So, if user submit value `Yes` you should check if `how_cool` field is populated too. You also should do this on client side to provide great user experience. Something like this with forms:

```
def clean_are_you_cool(self):
    if self.cleaned_data.get('are_you_cool', None) == 'Yes':
        if self.cleaned_data.get('how_cool', None) is not None:
           #  Actions for cool user. 
           pass
    #  Or if user not cool.
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay.  I had to work on some other code and decided to push this off until later.  I simply changed my code to something similar to [if data and data.get('drink', None) == "yes":]  instead of the self.YES and it worked.  This should work in most cases.  Thanks for the suggestion.